# Recycler view duplicates newly added item every time you load the activity again

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a chatting app. and in it i have a messaging system powered by firebase. and to load them on the front end I am using recycler view however every time I leave the activity and come back it is still fine but when I add a new message after coming back I duplicates

[if that seemed hard to understand here is a video showing what is happening](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RUciXN88T2KQt2rBB9gBa9pKc6b-Ckra/view?usp=sharing)

**Recycler View Adapter**

```
     public List<Chat> chatList;
    public FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    public DatabaseReference reference;
    public DatabaseReference dbRef;
    public String userid;


    public MessageAdapter(List<Chat> chat, String userId) {
        this.chatList = chat;
        this.userid = userId;
    }
    public class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView senderMessage, ReceiverMessage, sender_image_time, receiver_image_time, sender_name, receiver_name, sender_audio_time, receiver_audio_time;
        public ImageView messageSenderPicture,messageReceiverPicture;
        public CircleImageView receiver_profile_image, sender_profile_image, sender_audio_image, receiver_audio_image;
        public SeekBar sender_audio_bar, receiver_audio_bar;
        public ImageButton sender_audio_play, receiver_audio_play, sender_audio_pause, receiver_audio_pause;
        public ImageView sender_imageView, receiverImageView;
        public ConstraintLayout sender_audio_layout, receiver_audio_layout;

        public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        public Handler handler = new Handler();
        public Runnable runnable;

        public MessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            senderMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.senderText);
            ReceiverMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiverText);
            messageReceiverPicture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_receiver_image_view);
            messageSenderPicture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_sender_image_view);
            sender_image_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_time_image);
            receiver_image_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_time_image);
            receiver_profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_profile_image);
            sender_profile_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_profile_image);
            sender_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_name);
            receiver_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_name);
            sender_audio_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_audio_layout);
            receiver_audio_layout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_audio_layout);
            sender_audio_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_image_audio);
            receiver_audio_image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_image_audio);
            sender_audio_bar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
            receiver_audio_bar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_seekBar);
            sender_audio_play = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_play);
            receiver_audio_play = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_play);
            sender_audio_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_audio_time);
            receiver_audio_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_audio_time);
            sender_imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
            receiverImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_imageView4);
            sender_audio_pause = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sender_pause);
            receiver_audio_pause = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiver_pause);

            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_meeage_layout, parent, false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        return new MessageViewHolder(view);
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String messageSenderId = Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid();
        final Chat chat = chatList.get(position);

        String fromUserID = chat.getSender();
        String userID = chat.getReceiver();
        String fromMessageType = chat.getType();

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(fromUserID);
        dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userID);

        holder.senderMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.ReceiverMessage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.messageSenderPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.messageReceiverPicture.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.receiver_image_time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.sender_image_time.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.sender_profile_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.receiver_profile_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.sender_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.receiver_name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.sender_audio_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.receiver_audio_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if (fromMessageType.equals("text")) {
            if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderId)) {

                holder.senderMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.senderMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sender_layout);
                holder.senderMessage.setText(chat.getMessage() + "\n" + "       " + chat.getTime());

            } else {

                holder.senderMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.ReceiverMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.ReceiverMessage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.receiver_layout);
                holder.ReceiverMessage.setText(chat.getMessage() + "\n" + "       " + chat.getTime());

            }
    }else if (fromMessageType.equals("image")) {
            if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderId)) {
                holder.messageSenderPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                ref.child("Users").child(messageSenderId).child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            String name = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                            holder.sender_name.setText(name);
                        } else {}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                holder.sender_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                ref.child("Users").child(messageSenderId).child("image").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            String imageUrl = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.sender_profile_image);
                        } else {}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                holder.sender_profile_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Picasso.get().load(chat.getMessage()).into(holder.messageSenderPicture);
                holder.sender_image_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.sender_image_time.setText(chat.getTime());
            } else {
                holder.messageReceiverPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                ref.child("Users").child(userid).child("name").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            String name = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                            holder.receiver_name.setText(name);
                        } else {}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                holder.receiver_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                ref.child("Users").child(userid).child("image").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            String imageUrl = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.receiver_profile_image);
                        } else {}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                holder.receiver_profile_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Picasso.get().load(chat.getMessage()).into(holder.messageReceiverPicture);
                holder.receiver_image_time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.receiver_image_time.setText(chat.getTime());
            }
        } else if(fromMessageType.equals("audio")) {
            if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderId)) {
                holder.sender_audio_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                ref.child("Users").child(messageSenderId).child("image").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            String imageUrl = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.sender_audio_image);
                        } else {}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                holder.sender_audio_time.setText(chat.getTime());

                final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                holder.sender_audio_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        holder.sender_audio_play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.sender_audio_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        try {
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(chat.getMessage());
                            mediaPlayer.prepare();
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            holder.sender_audio_bar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        holder.sender_audio_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.sender_audio_pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        holder.sender_audio_bar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    }
                });

                holder.sender_audio_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        holder.sender_audio_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.sender_audio_pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        holder.sender_audio_bar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    }
                });
            } else {
                holder.receiver_audio_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                ref.child("Users").child(userid).child("image").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            String imageUrl = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.receiver_audio_image);
                        } else {}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                holder.receiver_audio_time.setText(chat.getTime());

                final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                holder.receiver_audio_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        holder.receiver_audio_play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.receiver_audio_pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        try {
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(chat.getMessage());
                            mediaPlayer.prepare();
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            holder.receiver_audio_bar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                        holder.receiver_audio_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.receiver_audio_pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        holder.receiver_audio_bar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    }
                });

                holder.receiver_audio_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        holder.receiver_audio_play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.receiver_audio_pause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                        holder.receiver_audio_bar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (fromUserID.equals(messageSenderId)) {
                holder.messageSenderPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                ref.child("Users").child(messageSenderId).child("image").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            String imageUrl = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.sender_profile_image);
                        } else {}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                holder.sender_profile_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.messageSenderPicture.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.file);

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(chatList.get(position).getMessage()));
                            holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Your Current Device Doesn't have the application to preview this file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                holder.messageReceiverPicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                ref.child("Users").child(userid).child("image").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                            String imageUrl = snapshot.getValue().toString();
                            Picasso.get().load(imageUrl).into(holder.receiver_profile_image);
                        } else {}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
                holder.receiver_profile_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.messageReceiverPicture.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.file);

                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(chatList.get(position).getMessage()));
                            holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Your Current Device Doesn't have the application to preview this file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return chatList.size();
    }


    }
```

**My Chat Activity**

```
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Toast.makeText(SarimPage.this, fUser.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); // Validate Id
        Global global = new Global();
        global.updateUserStatus("Active Now");
        reference.child("Users").child(Objects.requireNonNull(getIntent().getStringExtra("userID"))).child("userState")
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) {
                           String status21 = Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("state").getValue()).toString();
                           String time = Objects.requireNonNull(snapshot.child("time").getValue()).toString();

                           if (status21.equals("offline")) {
                               status2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                               userStatus.setText("Last Seen " + time);
                           }
                           if(status21.equals("online")) {
                               status2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                               status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                               userStatus.setText(status21);
                           }
                           if(status21.equals("Active Now")){
                               status2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                               status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                               userStatus.setText(status21);
                           }

                            if(status21.equals("typing...")){
                                status2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                userStatus.setText(status21);
                            }

                           if (status21.equals("away")) {
                               status3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                               userStatus.setText(status21);
                           }

                        } else {}
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

     reference.child("Messages").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
         @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
         @Override
         public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
             Chat chats = snapshot.getValue(Chat.class);

             assert chats != null;
             if(chats.getReceiver().equals(currentUser) && chats.getSender().equals(userID)
                     || chats.getReceiver().equals(userID) && chats.getSender().equals(currentUser)) {
                 chatList.add(chats);
             }

             messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             messageList.smoothScrollToPosition(Objects.requireNonNull(messageList.getAdapter()).getItemCount());

         }

         @Override
         public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {

         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

         }
     });

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onUserLeaveHint() {
        Global global = new Global();
        global.updateUserStatus("offline");
        chatList.clear();
        super.onUserLeaveHint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        chatList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        chatList.clear();
    }
```

Sorry there is way too much code in this activity so i am only showing methods i think will be usefull such as what i am doing on acitivty start stop or pause.

**Chat Model**

```
   public class Chat {
    private String sender;
    private String receiver;
    private String message;
    private String time;
    private String type;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Chat() {}

    public Chat(String sender, String receiver, String message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.receiver = receiver;
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getReceiver() {
        return receiver;
    }

    public void setReceiver(String receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public String getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    public void setSender(String sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

*(Also when i do this i want all the previous chat history to still be displayed)*

Answer (score 0):

Get same firebase instance when you reopen app.

```
     FirebaseDatabase database;

//always use this getFirebaseDatabase() method when you need database instance.

     public FirebaseDatabase getFirebaseDatabase() {
    
             if(database==null){
            database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
             }
            return database;
        }
```

Comment: Hi, if i do this then it will delete the old message when i add a new one i have tried this it didnt work, i want to keep the message history still there, thanks

Comment: I added a video so you can see better whats happening, hope that helps

Comment: When you add new message what was the chatlist size? if you have already 2 message when you add new message ,is chat list size is 3 or 5?@SarimmChaudhry

Comment: it increases so when it duplicates if i had 1 message and left the activity got it duplicated by 2 the size would be 3

Comment: Why did you  add your addValueEventListener within onStart()?@SarimmChaudhry

Comment: Looks like when you reopen the app ,new firebase instance get invoked. make chat list and firebase (reference) as static instance  .@SarimmChaudhry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this is the main source of your problems, but it seems like the `ChildEventListener` you're adding on `Messages` reference is being called every time the activity is launched or relaunched. This has the effect of adding multiple listener to the `Messages` reference (multiple time the lates child added to your `RecyclerView`), what you should do is to maybe move the

`reference.child("Messages").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {...}`

inside `onCreate` or make sure there is only one `ChildEventListener` listening to your `Messages` reference when launching your activity.

Hope this will help, have a good day :)

Comment: i dont have any on child event listners in the oncreate i am doing the message loading inside the method onStart, Thanks

Comment: that's what I'm saying you should move the things you're doing in `onCreate` or leave it where it is but most importantly make sure there is only one observer when launching your activity (to see how many observers are triggered add a logv inside `onChildAdded`)

Comment: I tried this, what ended up happeneing was that every time a came back to the actitivty to add a new message all the old chat histoury was deleted, thanks

Comment: I didn't quite get your comment, did my insight help to solve your problem or did it make it worst?

Comment: Well what happened was this kind of worked it just deleted all the old messages, i want keep my old message history displayed

Comment: I added a video so you can see better whats happening, hope that helps

Comment: I need access to watch the video, and it seems like you're cleaning your chat inside on stop and destroy try to remove those cleaning lines

Comment: if i remove the clean on stop and destroy it will duplicate the message history

Comment: I saw your video and it seems like the problem is as I described earlier, make sure your `chatList` variable is manipulated properly like, initialise le `chatList` inside `onCreate` using a `valueEventListener` then listen for new message locally or via `childEventListener` and remove the clean code in Stop and destroy